# Pass 'IN' list in SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, procedure

In a SQL procedure I need to pass an 'IN' list like below example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[In_List] 
(  @dept float
)
AS
BEGIN
select * from My_Table 
where departmentId in (@dept)
;
END

exec In_List 100 --Work fine
exec In_List 102,100 --Problem is passing in list
```

Can someone please help me how to pass IN list thru SQL procedure. Also I need to pass another variable which is `varchar`. These procedure will be used for SSRS reports.

Comment: Don't do anything, SSRS will pass the list from a multi-select parameter without any need to change the proc. Otherwise, try [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), or [upgrade to SQLS2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Comment: Why is @dept a float?

Comment: @JohnHC I don't think that will work with a stored proc. If the query from inside the stored proc is used as the dataset query then it will work (SSRS will pass it in correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to go dynamic:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[In_List] 
(  @dept float
)
AS
declare v_sql varchar(2000)
BEGIN
set v_sql = 'select * from My_Table where departmentId in (' + @dept + ');'
;
END
```

Then, in SSRS:

```
@dept = join(Parameters!dept.value, ",")
```

Or, if varchar:

```
@dept = join(Parameters!dept.value,"','")
```